# Secure Google maps static

Tags: google-maps

I'm using google static maps on my website, but I want to secure the APIKEY, so others can not use it. I already put my URL in the HTTP referrals, but I can still call https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=10%2C10&zoom=7&size=400x400&key=KEYAPI in the browser URL.

Is it possible to secure it or is it how google maps static API works?

I searched for similar questions but did not found any about this.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/google-maps-platform-best-practices-securing-api-keys-when-using-static-maps-and-street-view-apis

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#gen-sig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Google Maps API Keys are meant to be publically available in the browser. Yet, Google mentiones a few methods to secure your API key when using the Maps Static API:

> - Restrict your API keys
> - Digital signatures(3)
> - Independent API key per app
> - Delete API keys no longer needed
> - Exercise caution when regenerating keys
> - Monitor API key usage for anomalies
> - Do not embed signing secret directly in code
> - Do not store signing secret in source tree
> - Review code before public release

### Digital signatures

You can further limit what limits which requests can be made using your API key by adding a digital signature to your requests.

This example query `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714%2c%20-73.998&zoom=12&size=400x400&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&signature=<BASE64_SIGNATURE>` is valid *only* for the parameters `center=40.714%2c%20-73.998&zoom=12&size=400x400`.

This further makes it impractical for someone to reuse your API key for their own site.

This explains how to use digital signatures: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#gen-sig

---

Correction from my previous reply:

**DO NOT** try to cache or proxy the Maps Static API as it is against Google's terms of service.

Comment: 1) You link and quote *Premium Plan* documentation which is most likely not what OP is using 2) No caching is allowed for the Maps Static API 3) The Maps Static API documentation mentions other recommendations that you haven't mentioned or explained.

Comment: @MrUpsidown You are 100% correct... I've corrected my answer.

Comment: It may be required to change the quota on unsigned requests to zero.

Comment: thanks everyone, I did that. used the signature and then put the unsigned quota to 0.